# Fast UPDATE Thousands Records in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update thousands of records in a DB.
For example...

I have a table named `images` that contains about `600,000` rows and
another table named `articles` containing `250,000` rows.

**I need to replace oldimage urls with newimage urls.**

So I use the following below

```
UPDATE articles set body = replace(body,'SEARCH','REPLACE');
```

But it's so slow to repeat. Now just 4000 UPDATE Query done after about 8 hours.

Are there solutions that will produce a much faster result?

Comment: Are the columns indexed?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Body Column has FullText Index.

Comment: drop the index, make the replacements, create the index back. If that is still slow consider dumping the data to a file, replace it there, update records (without index).

Comment: what do you mean by "slow to repeat"? are you complaining about the fact that the query itself is slow or that you need to repeat this query for each of the 600k images?

Comment: @koriander Great Idea ... "dumping the data to a file, replace it there, update records" let me test.

Comment: @milo5b i need to repeat this for all records... let me say ... it must be about 150000000000 query.

Comment: beware, the big bottleneck should be the index, not the replacement

Comment: I think koriander's suggestion is a good one, but just to be clear, how are you currently repeating these queries? Retrieving all images from DB, generating new and old paths, and then running the UPDATE query for each pair of paths in a loop?

Comment: @milo5b i created a simple php file to create **UPDATE articles set body = replace(body,'SEARCH','REPLACE');** per query ... and echo it. then i copy & paste it in phpmyadmin and run.

Comment: @koriander i add fulltext index after 5 hours.

Comment: you mean, the index takes 5 hours to build?

Comment: @koriander no. after 5 hours, that table doesnt have an index, i add it. it take 5 minutes to build. let me say ... each query to run take abt 5-10 second. it must be run 250000*600000.

Comment: hmm, the query above only processes the table Articles, thus 250,000 records. I think something is missing in your question

Comment: I think UFO is saying that there are 600000 replace queries to be run

Comment: right... sorry. 600000 **UPDATE articles set body = replace(body,'SEARCH','REPLACE');** mean how many hours ? i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

as **koriander** said,

```
"dumping the data to a file, replace it there, update records"
```

is so fast.

after 3 hours, about 8000 images replaced in DB.

thank you again.

Comment: nice, thks for your feedback!